# Is std::future::get() or std::future::wait() a replacement for std::thread::join()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, future

Will a thread join back like `thread.join()` after invoking `future.get()`/`future.wait()` of the future get from it? Can I join a thread only using its future without direct access to that thread?

Comment: `std::future` doesn't have anything to do with `std::thread`. Therefore, you use `std::thread::join` only if you use `std::thread`. Under the `std::future` hood, there is a thread pool that accepts the job and distributes it in a smart way

Comment: It's not a replacement, as NutCracker explains, but it's *similar* and perhaps that's what you're asking: both share the concept of waiting until something (be it a thread, or thread pool, or...) is done

Comment: @LiamYoung it would be good if you could provide us some feedback. If you liked one of the answers, upvote it and accept the best answer (that's this green tick used for ;))

Comment: @NutCracker I have selected a best answer for me and I've upvoted all the answers. Unfortunately stackoverflow does not present upvotes from users with a repution lower than 15. Anyway thank you for your kind remind and enlightening answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is `std::future::get()` or `std::future::wait()` a replacement for `std::thread::join()`?*

No, these are different things.

`std::future` is a synchronization tool. It is a wrapper around a *value* that is not immediately available, but is going to be. It is used for communicating data from an asynchronous operation (which can run in another thread). Under the hood it contains a semaphore on which `get()` waits, if needed.

A `std::thread` on the other hand represents an actual execution thread. It can produce multiple results and thus feed multiple `std::promise`s during its lifetime. Which it should, because starting and joining a thread is a relatively heavyweight operation, much heavier than waiting on a future. That's why one should prefer to re-use threads, posting async operations to a thread pool and waiting for their results (`std::packaged_task` is a useful abstraction for that).

A thread will not immediately exit after `std::future::get()`, even if setting the promise is the last thing it does. These are unrelated events.

Answer (score 3):

When using `future` you are not 100% sure that an actual new thread is created. For instance when you create a `future` using the `std::launch::deferred` execution policy, the execution is very much serial.

Quoting the standard:

> `std::launch::deferred`: the task is executed on the calling thread the
>   first time its result is requested (lazy evaluation)

---

In practice when you create a `future` with the `std::launch::async` execution policy most of the time a new thread is launched. Examining the generated code with `gcc 10` I can clearly see that `thread::join` is called:

```
std::__future_base::_Async_state_commonV2::_M_complete_async():
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        //more assembly maddness
        call    std::__future_base::_Async_state_commonV2::_M_join()
```

which in turn lead to a `thread::join()` invocation.

```
std::__future_base::_Async_state_commonV2::_M_join():
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $48, %rsp
        movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
        movq    -40(%rbp), %rcx
        addq    $32, %rcx
        movq    %rcx, -24(%rbp)
        movl    $std::thread::join(), %eax
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, `std::future` doesn't have anything to do with `std::thread`. Therefore, you use `std::thread::join` only if you use `std::thread` and you use `std::future::get`/`std::future::wait` if you use `std::future`.

Under the `std::future` hood, there is a thread pool that accepts the job and distributes it in a smart way.